# Too small error on a physics lab

Tags: derivatives, error-propagation

I have this function:
$$\lambda=d \sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)\right)$$ and I want to find its absolute error.
d is a constant ($10^{-6}$), x is $(0.716 \pm 0.001) m $ , and z is $(1.000 \pm 0.001) m $.
For the error of $\lambda$, $$\Delta\lambda=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial x}\Delta x\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial z}\Delta z\right)^2}=d\sqrt{\left(\frac{z\Delta x}{(z^2+x^2)(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+1})}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x\Delta z}{(z^2+x^2)(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{z^2}+1})}\right)^2}$$

And I have obtained $6.6 \cdot 10^{-10} m$. I expect a much larger error. What's wrong? The formula?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think this is better suited for Physics.SE.

Comment: @IanMateus the question it's all about error-propagation theory and formulas... so I have posted here to be sure to not have done mathematical mistakes..

Comment: No problem, this is for future questions. But it would be more likely to receive more attention there, I think.

Comment: @IanMateus ok, thank you. Could you confirm me that I haven't made mistakes in the derivations?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to deal with such questions.

Comment: Looks like the right ball-park to me. The $10^{-3}$ errors on $x$ and $z$ propagate to give something of the same magnitude, multiply with $d = 10^{-6}$, you have an error of magnitude $\approx 10^{-9}$. None of the involved functions blows up an error anywhere, and the division only blows up near $z = 0$.

Comment: This is cross-posted  to Physics [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/too-small-error-on-the-calculus-of-wavelenght/90544#90544)

Comment: Taking the derivatives is much easier if you recognize that $\sin (\arctan \frac xz)=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$ but you did fine.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: when dealing with error propagation, try always to reduce the problem as much as possible. It's terribly easy to make a mistake when dealing with those little numbers. Now, note that for positive $\cos t$ you have:  $$\sin t= \tan t \cos t=\frac{\tan t}{\sqrt{1+\tan ^2t}}.$$
Substituting $t=\arctan \xi$, you get:$$ \sin (\arctan \xi)=\dfrac{\xi}{\sqrt{1+\xi ^2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\xi ^{-2}+1}}.$$
Now:

a) Compute the uncertainty for $\xi ^{-1}=z/x.$

b) $\Delta({\sqrt{1+t}})\approx\dfrac{d{\sqrt{1+t}}}{dt}\cdot \Delta t=\dfrac{\Delta t}{2\sqrt{1+t}}.$

c) The relative uncertainty for $1/p$ is the same of $p$ (why?).